# stack a pandas dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user':[1,2,2,3], 'date':['2023-04-12', '2023-04-13', '2023-04-15','2023-04-18'], 
                   'variable':['x1','x1','x2','x1'], 'sth':['xx','yy','yy','zz']})
```

```
user    date    variable    sth
0   1   2023-04-12  x1  xx
1   2   2023-04-13  x1  yy
2   2   2023-04-15  x2  yy
3   3   2023-04-18  x1  zz
```

and would like to stack it such that I receive this dataframe

```
user    sth x1  x2
0   1   xx  2023-04-12  NaN
1   2   yy  2023-04-13  2023-04-15
2   3   zz  2023-04-18  NaN
```

How do I need to do this?

Comment: `df.pivot(index=['user', 'sth'], columns='variable', values='date').reset_index()`

Comment: This does not work: ValueError: Length of passed values is 4, index implies 2

Comment: This certainly works with the provided example, please update your question if needed.

Comment: I have copy pasted the exact thing I have written above and I get this error above. Does it work for you?

Comment: pivot does not accept list of columns as index so you need to use pivot_table.pd.pivot_table(df, index=['user', 'sth'], columns='variable', values='date',aggfunc= 'first' ).reset_index()

Comment: It does. Which pandas version are you using (`print(pd.__version__)`)? Likely an old one.